# Appending an array within JSON array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, join, inner-join

I am using `MySQL 8` and trying to update `JSON data type` in a `mysql table`

My `table t1` looks as below:

```
# id    key     value   
1100000 key123  [{"name": "name1", "hosts": ["host123"]}]
```

Now, I have a list of hosts `hostlist` as below:

```
SET @hostlist = '["host343", "host345"]';
```

I want to append `@hostlist` to the `hosts` array within `value` JSON Array:

```
UPDATE table t1
        SET t1.value = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('[]', '$', JSON_OBJECT('hosts', @hostlist))
        WHERE t1.key = 'key123';
```

`Desired Output:`

```
[{"name": "name1", "hosts": ["host123","host343", "host345"]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a path to the `hosts` property in the existing `value` and append to that.

But `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()` is for appending a single value to the array. You need to use `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE()` to concatenate arrays. Then use `JSON_REPLACE()` to replace the array with this.

```
UPDATE t1
SET value = JSON_REPLACE(t1.value, '$[0].hosts', JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(t1.value->'$[0].hosts', @hostlist))
WHERE t1.key = 'key123';
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v69yGhqu9jezfWttWue2JY/0)